# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" in form

Tags: laravel, vue.js

An error is returned when I try to post the form.

The form is in a component, and the same structure is used in another component but does not generate any error.

I tried to find the mistake by myself but impossible to find the solution.

```
<template>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;margin:0 0 1rem 1rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="mt-3 text-center" style="cursor:pointer;" @click="show=!show" >Add list</h4>
                  <form v-show="show" @submit.prevent="submitList">
                        <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Title</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" :class="{'is-invalid':errors.title}" v-model="form.title"/>
                              <p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.title" v-text="errors.title[0]"></p>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success mb-4">Submit</button>
                  </form>
            </div>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
      data() {
            return {
                  show : false,
                  form: {
                        title: '',
                  },
                  errors: {}
            }
      },
      methods: {
            submitList() {
                  axios.post('/list', this.form)
                        .then(({data}) => {
                              this.$emit('newList', data),
                              this.form.title = '',
                              this.show = false,
                              this.errors = {}
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                              this.errors = error.response.data.errors
                        })
            }
      }
}
</script>
```

Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Reference `this` at the start of the method `submitList` and then use the reference in the axios response.

```
let that = this;
```

then `that.form.title;`

```
submitList () {
  let that = this;
  axios.post('/list', this.form)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      that.$emit('newList', data),
        that.form.title = '',
        that.show = false,
        that.errors = {}
    })
    .catch(error => {
      that.errors = error.response.data.errors
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that does not correct anything

Comment: This shouldn't be needed as the => operator keeps the scope, you only need to declare this when using the older function() syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information here to answer the question. Since it's a render issue my guess is that it's one of these lines:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" :class="{'is-invalid':errors.title}" v-model="form.title"/>
<p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.title" v-text="errors.title[0]"></p>
```

The question is what you get from the backend in your catch method. You should probably log that value and check that it's formated the way you think it is.

A nice tool for debugging Vue is the [browser extension](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools), maybe it will help with clearing up the problem.

If this does not solve your problem you need to provide more info:

- When does the error occur
- What is the value of the data-properties when it occurs
- Maybe a screenshot of a more thorough error-message